# Texnic center and Adobe Acrobat DC, again²

Tags: texniccenter, adobe

I have the same problem with TeXnicCenter and Adobe Acrobat DC **Version 2022.001.20169** with 64-bit version like some other users with older DC versions. Everytime I compile with Latex => PDF, the following warning occurs:

[DocOpen("%bm.pdf")]... Cannot execute the command.

Although I checked in the registry (Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application) and used the denoted results "**AcroViewA22**" for the output profile, it is not working. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same symptoms whe I compile with Texmaker AND open the pdf externally in Acrobat Reader (AR).

**Solution**:
Close the window, showing your compiled document, in AR and compile in Texmaker.